# "it is only when .... that ...." usage

Tags: grammar

I've been having a very difficult time figuring out the grammar behind the following sentence:

> Desertion can also be explained by the animalistic nature of soldiers; it is only when soldiers confront the face of death that they recognize their own mortality and escape the dangers in the battlefield before them.

There's something about the second part that just doesn't feel right. How do I fix the part after the semicolon in order to make it just better/gramatically correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false assumption that the text is not grammatically correct.

Comment: What @Drew said. Any alternative phrasing just amounts to Lit Crit/writing advice.

Comment: Why is it grammatically correct? How can you show that?

Comment: The burden of proof is on the person who claims it is wrong to say what they think is wrong with it. You have not done that, and in fact, there is nothing wrong with it, and so there is no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the inversion req'd by "only":

*Desertion can also be explained by the animalistic nature of soldiers. **Only** when soldiers confront the face of death **do they recognize**  their own mortality **and** **try to escape** the dangers in the battlefield before them.*

> [Thyroid Balance: Traditional and Alternative Methods for ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tEW5D3RRK74C&pg=PA70&dq=%22only%20when%22%20%22do%20they%20recognize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SmkkVYN87-OwBJmOgMAB&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22only%20when%22%20%22do%20they%20recognize%22&f=false) - Page 70
>   Glenn S. Rothfeld, ‎Deborah S. Romaine - 2002
>
> **Only when** treatment with thyroid supplement restores the balance of thyroid hormone in their bodies **do they recognize** that they
>   hadn't been feeling up to par.

Comment: But there's absolutely nothing wrong with the original. You do save a couple of words, but no clarity or "grammaticality" is added. That is, both forms are equally grammatical and equally understandable. If one sounds better, then use it, as a matter of _style_, not grammar. This was essentially a writing style question, not a grammar question.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock The insertion of 'try to' vastly improves the original. But that wasn't part of the question, as far as I can see. +1.